# SQL window function and (date+interval) as a border of range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to use hard borders for RANGE?

The correct code is:

```
SELECT user_id,
       created_at,
       COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY created_at 
                      RANGE BETWEEN '30 days' PRECEDING 
                                AND '30 days' FOLLOWING) AS qty_in_period
```

But this sample is wrong:

```
SELECT user_id,
       created_at,
       COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY created_at 
                      RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                AND (reg_date+interval) FOLLOWING) AS qty_in_period
```

reg_date is timestamp type, interval is '1 month'.

I know, it can be done with WHERE construction but I need to check possibility to do it via window function.

Please help.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and tag the database you're using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to use hard borders for `RANGE`?

No. The documentation is [explicit about it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> In the `offset PRECEDING` and `offset FOLLOWING` frame options, the `offset` must be an expression not containing any variables, aggregate functions, or window functions.

Attempting to use such syntax raises the following error:

> ERROR:  argument of RANGE must not contain variables

One alternative uses a correlated subquery, or lateral join. The last query in your example could be written as:

```
select user_id, created_at, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) qty_in_period
    from mytable t1
    where t1.created_at <= t.created_at + t.intval
) x
```